# How can I add specific header file to index as if it was included in eclipse cdt?

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am working in ffreestanding environment (custom make builder, which works fine), but indexer seems to have trouble with default gcc includes that you can query by

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

which I really need, so I exported them to header but I don't want to include it, is there a way to make indexer take that file as "included" everywhere (because it really is).

I have eclipse cdt 8.8.0

Comment: _Freestanding environment_ does not refer to your build environment, but the run-time environment (i.e. the target).

Comment: so then what, indexer is useless?

Comment: No idea; it is unclear what you are actually diong, want to accomplish and what you are asking. Read [ask].

Comment: What did you not get in my question? If I am using custom builder then indexer does not get the base definitions that gcc provides. So I am wondering how I can add them back to the indexer

Comment: "I use custom builder" So how would we be able to know your builder? Sorry I'm no clairvoyant.

Comment: custom builder as in make script, do you need to know the contents of it? Because indexer does not call it...

Comment: A builder is not make. But make is a build-tool. Possibly to your surprise there are other build-tools (some are much easier to use, e.g. you don't have to care about dependencies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDT has a mechanism to discover the compiler's built-in include paths and defines, called the **Built-in Compiler Settings provider**.

This provider is configured in Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Providers tab -> CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings.

Make sure this provider is enabled, and adjust the "Command to get compiler specs" as appropriate, and CDT should start picking up the compiler's built-in settings.